# What happened to the "greater enemy" plot of Old Republic series?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-the-old-republic

In the Old Republic series, Revan embraced the dark side because he believed it was needed to defeat a "greater enemy" of some kind.

Some of the possible endings, that overlap with canon ending in Kotor1 and 2 result into a bunch of "grayish" Jedi and Sith looking for that "greater enemy"

Since Kotor3 never happened, I wonder, did the writers ever used that plotline, or it was abandoned? Who was that "greater enemy" that was dangerous to the point of someone believing it was good idea to use the republic + sith empire at the same time against it?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! I hope you this stack as enjoyable as have the others you are a member of.

Comment: commenting on my own question: while looking for something else entirely, I found out notes from Kotor2 writer about this.

His intention was for the greater enemy be the "true sith", as in a sith lord of the actual red-skinned sith race, and his underlings.

Comment: you can always answer your own question as well. "Word of god" always makes a good answer

Comment: I hadn't heard of that at all, speeder.  As @Skooba mentions, link a good source and post it as an answer.  Even if it wasn't eventually used that way, it's good info.

Comment: I heard about it too. only thing is they retconned it as soon as they made the mmo (hate that but sadly normal in the industry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the two other answers were posted (and they are good ones), I found more information while looking into something else.

The original source is this podcast:

I found it because of this post: https://www.reddit.com/r/kotor/comments/58zcn2/obsidians_story_for_kotor_3/

The summary of Chris Avellone (Kotor 2 writer) about Kotor 3 is:

- Exile would be the PC and Revan would be an NPC.
- HK-47 and T3-M4 would be your starting companions.
- Game would be set in Unknown Regions in the teritory of the True Sith.
- True Sith were meant to appear incomprehensibly vicious and menacing.
- Plot would revolve around finding Revan and a way to defeat True Sith.
- True Sith were not merely a sect of Sith but were actually the original Sith Lords.

Also based on that, I presume that Kreia reasoning for her actions in Kotor2 were correct: Revan DID intentionally attacked the Republic as a "fake" Sith as a means to force the Republic to prepare for the "True Sith" that were preparing a surprise attack.

Answer (score 5):

The greater enemy that Revan foresaw was the Sith Emperor.

Much of the initial focus in *SW:TOR* (which can be considered in a way to be KoToR 3) is given to the sudden re-emergence of the Sith Empire, and their blitzkrieg attack on Republic planets.  An easy interpretation of Revan's warning was that this mighty empire was hiding in the shadows and ready to attack at any time.  This tends to fall apart given that Revan himself used the name of Sith, as well as the Dark Side, in his misguided attempt to prepare the Republic.  The Sith Empire, for all it's evils, was an acceptable outcome and not what Revan was worried about.

The Sith Emperor on the other hand (known also as Valkorion, or as Lord Vitiate), is a shadowy figure even to his own people.  His goal is true immortality, and he's already made some headway on it.  He captured Revan and what remained of Revan's followers shortly after Revan came back to the Outer Rim hunting for him, and has kept both himself and Revan alive in the intervening centuries (Revan has gone quite a bit mad as a result).  The Emperor puts the Sith Lords seen in KoToR 2 to shame in sheer power.  He set up the war - which the Sith wanted at any rate - specifically to draw strength from the deaths it would provide.  He would sacrifice anything and anyone - people, planets, up to and including his entire Empire - if it aids his quest to become immortal, and thus stands as the true foe for the series as a whole, even for those allied with the Sith.

Comment: One thing though revan didn't just foresaw the sith emperor. He MET him and during that meeting and the fight he fell and became darth revan as far as I'm aware (together with his best friend who betrayed him in the backstory of kotor 1).

Comment: @Thomas - yeah, I'm seeing that in a bunch of wiki entries, but I'm not seeing anything about how that meeting actually went down, which makes it kinda sketchy.  Jedi don't just go nutso and crazy simply because they run into a Sith lord, even that one; Revan's "method" of turning Jedi by exposing them to a place of death and despair simply made it much easier.  Maybe he was just scared witless.

Comment: from what I read it was very Anakin like......revan and his friuend got their buts handed to them by the sith emperor and thus gave in to their sorrow and anger and fell and became sith lords themselves. In all honesty I never really got that part as it makes no sense (and he is more powerful than I am.....there is always someone moer powerful...no need to switch sides just because of that)

Answer (score 2):

The greater enemy as revealed in the online game The Old Republic was the Sith emperor (and in extension the Sith empire). This was a bit further expanded upon in the Revan book and then again in the MMO where it was told how Revan got to know the enemy, why Revan fell and what happened after Kotor 2.